# What would make a good portable clean target in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, portability

What is the appropriate form for a `clean` target for a portable Makefile?  `$(RM)` does not work for me.  I work both from the Windows (7) command prompt and within Eclipse.  They both report the same version of make (I do have multiple on my path):

```
make --version 
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i386-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Within Eclipse:

```
make clean 
rm -f *.o testScaffolding_* runner.cpp runner.exe *.d
```

From cmd:

```
rm -f *.o testScaffolding_* runner.cpp runner.exe *.d
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f *.o testScaffolding_* runner.cpp runner.exe *.d, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Both report `$(OS)` as `Windows_NT` and `$(RM)` as `rm -f`.  I have which installed as well and if I call it within the Makefile, both environments report the same path.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I've come up with so far.  You can specify `UNAME` as an environment variable or on the command line.  If not specified it tries to run uname.  If that fails it assumes Windows.  Subsequently, you have a reasonable guess as to your shell environment and can define the corresponding commands appropriately.

Note that this has seen only limited testing and I merely consider it functional, not elegant or 'correct'.  Also, the likes of an executable extension (`.exe` vs. nothing) is probably better identified by the use of `$(OS)`.

```
ifeq ($(strip $(UNAME)),)
# if not already specified, try running uname
UNAME = $(shell uname)
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(UNAME)),)
# if still not specified, assume Windows
UNAME = Windows
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),Windows)
define TO_WIN
$(subst /,\,$1)
endef
define MKDIR
-mkdir $(call TO_WIN,$1)
endef
define RM
del $(call TO_WIN,$1)
endef
CAT := type
else
define MKDIR
mkdir -p $1
endef
define RM
rm -f $1
endef
CAT := cat
endif
```